# Fund single output in PSBT with bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, bip174-psbt

I would like to create a PSBT with a single output (P2WSH with a given/predefined amount) in an app and give that to the user. The user should then be able to fund this PSBT with the help of `bitcoind` and/or a hardware wallet.
With "fund" I mean add an input with sufficient balance, perform fee estimation and add a change output if necessary.
The fully funded and finalized (all inputs signed/witnesses added) PSBT would then be given back to the app to continue the workflow.

My question: Is there a workflow with `bitcoind` that allows that? I have tried `walletprocesspsbt` but that only adds an input, no change output. And there are no parameters for fee estimation.

An alternative workflow that would fit my use case would be to use `walletcreatefundedpsbt` where the user would specify the *amount* of the output to fund but leave the address/PK script to be defined. But as I understand the `walletcreatefundedpsbt` command, the address has to be given for an output. Or could the `data` part be used to mark an output as "incomplete"/"to be defined"?

Comment: You should have the user call walletcreatefundedpsbt with the address/amount you want, which will then add inputs and change. If that's what you mean by the "alternative workflow", what is the problem with it?

Comment: That's what I currently do as a workaround. But I was wondering if there was a way to transport the parameters in a PSBT directly instead of the user copy/pasting individual values and potentially mistyping the amount. So it's probably just a question about user experience at this point. I just wanted to make sure there isn't something obvious I missed in any of the PSBT commands/options.

Comment: Ah, PSBT only functions in the pipeline as of the stage where you have an actual transaction (ignoring witness/scriptSigs), so you need to know the inputs/outputs before you can talk about a PSBT.